# Jquery auto change class on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class `.render-inner.render-letter` and I made with jquery to add classes (*red, blue, green, yellow*) to the existing one (`.render-inner.render-letter yellow` , `.render-inner.render-letter blue` ...) with a click of mouse.
How do I make classes constantly change without a mouse click and without stopping?

here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.render-inner.render-letter') .addClass('green');        
var classes = ['red','blue','yellow','green'],
        i = 0;
    $('.render-inner.render-letter').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass(classes[i])
               .addClass(classes[ i = ++i % classes.length ]);         
    });
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: By using setinterval. Shouldn't be too difficult I hope

Comment: `setInterval(function () { $(".render-inner.render-letter").removeClass(classes[i]).addClass(classes[(i = ++i % classes.length)]); }, 3000);`

Comment: no problem, glad to help